# Xcode 11 Upload through commandline stucks

Tags: ios, command-line, upload, xcode11, xcrun

As the application loader is now gone with Xcode 11, I tried to upload my app through the commandline tool xcrun altool.
I first created an apiKey on app store connect. Then I used this command to upload my app:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type iOS --file <path-to-ipa> --apiKey <keyID> --apiIssuer <IssuerID> --verbose
```

I saw some logs and it seemed that it is working, but then it got stucked here:

> 2019-09-26 15:33:38.362 altool[62528:4432964] Using tool '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Resources/DTAppAnalyzerExtractor'.
>   2019-09-26 15:33:38.362 altool[62528:4432964] 'DTAppAnalyzerExtractor': self.executablePath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Resources/DTAppAnalyzerExtractor
>   2019-09-26 15:33:38.363 altool[62528:4432964] Launching: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Resources/DTAppAnalyzerExtractor --input-dir /var/folders/_1/7_lm5w6j5px21sd311p2g7340000gn/T/xxx.ipa --output-file /var/folders/_1/7_lm5w6j5px21sd311p2g7340000gn/T/DTAppAnalyzerExtractorOutput-DCBxxx406xxB4E-Cxxx6C53F2.zip
>   2019-09-26 15:33:42.725 altool[62528:4432963] Web service call (validateSoftwareSPIUsage) result: (null)
>   2019-09-26 15:33:42.856 altool[62528:4432963] Using template named: purple-metadata-template
>   2019-09-26 15:33:42.858 altool[62528:4432956] Sending request to iTunesTransporter...
>   2019-09-26 15:33:42.859 altool[62528:4432956]     Command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
>   2019-09-26 15:33:42.859 altool[62528:4432956]   Arguments: -m upload -u 'xxx@icloud.com' -vp json -TxHeaders eyJqZW5xxxxxXRlIjoicHYifQ== -sessionid @env:0028Bxxxxx8D1xxxxxxx-BFxxxxA75 -sharedsecret @env:xxxxxxxx -f '/var/folders/_1/7_lm5wxxxxp2g7340000gn/T/8B0E8xxx4AD7-A547-4xxBD53/1219768922.itmsp' -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client='altool' -Dtransporter.client.version='4.00 (1181)'
>   2019-09-26 15:33:45.901 altool[62528:4432953] 
>   [2019-09-26 15:33:45 MESZ]   INFO: Configuring logging...
>   2019-09-26 15:33:45.914 altool[62528:4432953] [2019-09-26 15:33:45 MESZ]   INFO: Logging level set to eXtreme

Does someone has the same Problem and found a solution for this?

**EDIT:**

Okay I solved the problem. I deleted xcode (and all it dependencies) and reinstalled it. Restarted my mac and then it worked.

Comment: Why not simply upload from the Xcode Organizer where you see the list of archives? No command line needed.

Comment: I also tried this, but it got stucked on "Authenticating ...". Thats why I tried to do it with command-line.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by running `altool` with `sudo`, after **restart** my MacBook.

`sudo xcrun altool --upload-app -t ios -f xxx.ipa -u xxx -p xxx --verbose`

It will not stuck any more.

```
2019-12-18 23:53:30.676 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:30 CST] <main>  INFO: Configuring logging...
2019-12-18 23:53:30.691 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:30 CST] <main>  INFO: Logging level set to eXtreme
2019-12-18 23:53:30.696 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:30 CST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is searching for new software components.
2019-12-18 23:53:30.696 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:30 CST] <main>  INFO: INFO: using cached repository.xml file.
2019-12-18 23:53:42.705 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:42 CST] <pool-3-thread-2>  INFO: Download complete for: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore/4.4.11.
2019-12-18 23:53:42.746 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:42 CST] <main>  INFO: indexing file: /var/root/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.4.11.jar
2019-12-18 23:53:42.784 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:42 CST] <main>  INFO: indexing file: /var/root/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.9.10.jar
2019-12-18 23:53:42.787 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:42 CST] <main>  INFO: indexing file: /var/root/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.felix.scr-2.1.14.jar
2019-12-18 23:53:42.796 altool[7779:157434] [2019-12-18 23:53:42 CST] <main>  INFO: indexing file: /var/root/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/obr/2.0.0/org.apache.logging.log4j.api-2.11.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xcodebuild` is better

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /pathTo/ExportOptionsUpload.plist -archivePath /pathTo/App.xcarchive
```

`ExportOptionsUpload.plist` include

```
<key>destination</key>
<string>upload</string>
```

See detail by

```
man xcodebuild
```

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes?language=objc)   Since Xcode 10,`xcodebuild` add New Features